Is there a name for this type of matrices?
I was wondering if we have a name for the class of square matrices with the property that the diagonal entries are all the same. For example, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is an example of a matrix satisfying this property, which is not diagonal (unless the base commutative ring is zero).
Other examples include $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 & 7 \\ 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 9 & 10 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 3 & 7 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & 5 \\ 9 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 8 & 7 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.
Also, I would love to know if we have a name for the class of square matrices with the property that the diagonal entries are all $1$ (the identity of the base commutative ring).

Could you give more examples (larger square matrices)? Given this single example, I would guess this is a Jordan block.

@DuongNgo Thank you for the comment. I have added two more examples to the question.

I know diagonal dominant matrices and tridiagonal matrices but these are not really what you are looking for. The second example is a particular case of yours and has easy to compute determinants (and generalises I think) but in the end it won't be close enough of what you are looking for. What motivates you to study this?

I do not think that there is a name for those matrices. To the best of my knowledge, those matrices do not have any special properties but the one that all diagonal elements are the same. If you are planning to write a paper, article, thesis etc. and you often have to refer to that sort of matrices, you can introduce a name yourself at the beginning, make sure that this name is different from any existing well-established term and then use it consistently throughout the article.

Also if you have $|A| <1$ you have $(I_n-A)$ invertible and its inverse is $\sum A^k$ so you could generalise it to $aI_n - B$ with $|B|<|a|$

The answer is no.

@julio_es_sui_glace Thank you. It appeared as a sufficient condition on the matrix presentation of a certain endomorphism in my research, which yields a similar consequence as known results, which I was trying to generalize. It seems like this property is not even stable under replacing it with a similar matrix, so I might not give a name.

Such a name is only given for particular special cases, like the subgroup $U_n(K)$ of (upper)-unitriangular matrices in the group $GL_n(K)$, consisting of upper-triangular matrices with all diagonal elements equal to $1$.
If $D_n(K)$ denotes the subgroup of invertible diagonal matrices, then we have a semidirect product
$$
GL_n(K)= D_n(K)\ltimes U_n(K).
$$
